# Add button to map

Tags: arcgis-10.1, javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, html, dojo

I know this is a a stupid and direct question.

How do I add a button to a normal map?

Example: http://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/samples/map_simple/

I'm finding a way to make a button appear on the top of the screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you must be having map div.put following code

```
<div id="map">
    <input id="Addlyr" type="submit"  value = "Add Layer" style="position: absolute; z-index: 1000; left: 100px; float: right;" />
</div>
```

if you want new button and put nice style adjust using css in style attribute of input button.

If you are referring + and - button then those button are default zoom button which can be initialized in map properties.

Comment: for some reason it appear out of the map boundary.

Comment: adjust left, right and float value...

Comment: See example #4 in this nice tutorial to understand absolute positioning within a relative div, http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/